# How do I convert a dynamic JSON array to a CSV in Java

Tags: java, json, csv, jackson, gson

I am trying to create a CSV file from a dynamically generated JSON array. For example:

```
"People" : 
[{"name" : "Bob", "age" : 5 },
 {"dob" : "5/2/4", "name" : "Alice"},
 {"name" : "George"}]
```

would create the csv file

```
name, age, dob
Bob, 5, 
Alice, , 5/2/4
George, ,
```

As you can see, I need to create a column for every field in the JSON array. The order of each key-value pair in the JSON array is random. I also do not know name of the keys beforehand. Don't worry about the "People" field, there will only be one array in each JSON. (This will most be the CSV name).

I have tried using the [Jackson CSV library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv) but this requires me to create a pre-defined POJO as a middle tier (JSON -> POJO -> CSV). As far as I know, Java does not allow me to dynamically generate a class' member variables at run time, so this method will not work. Same with [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).

I will need to do this over a large data set, so efficiency would be pretty key. What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: hey, i am having a similar problem. Were u able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use streaming API to parse the json data. Jackson library, or json-simple support streaming parse of JSON data. To produce CSV use CSVWriter from opencsv.

Comment: I am very well aware of the technologies available and the high level solution. My problem is more complex than sticking APIs together. I am dealing with dynamically generated and randomly ordered elements in an JSON array. My final output CSV has to be structured and columns have to be ordered according to a specific schema (as shown above).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library [**json2flat**](https://github.com/opendevl/Json2Flat). It **doesn't** requires any **POJO's** in order to convert.

You simply need to pass the your **JSON** as string.

For the following JSON:

```
{
    "People" : 
        [
            {"name" : "Bob", "age" : 5 },
            {"dob" : "5/2/4", "name" : "Alice"},
            {"name" : "George"}
        ]
}
```

The output is:

```
/People/name,/People/age,/People/dob
"Bob",5,
"Alice",,"5/2/4"
"George",,
```